C++ sort int array
typedef long long i64;

bool compare(i64 *a, i64 *b)
{
    if (*(a + 1) != *(b + 1))
    {
        return *(a + 1) > *(b + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return *a < *b;
    }
}

int main(){
    i64 final[100][2] = {
        0,
    };
    i64 final_stack = 0;

    //....(after inserting data)

    sort(final, final + final_stack, compare);
}

i can't sort int array like this.
complie error says, there is problem with "compare" function.
Any one plz help..
i tried,

bool compare(const i64 *a, const i64 *b)
bool compare(void *a, void *b)

none of these worked

Unrelated: Avoid naming your array final. It is an identifier with special meaning.

If you have build errors, then please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output into your question.

On a different note, please don't make up your own type-aliases. There's std::int64_t that you can use. And what is the reason to use 64-bit integers, that can't be solved by plain int? Also, for any pointer p and index i, the expression *(p + i) is exactly equal to p[i]. Which also means that *p is equal to p[0].

Why you do not use std::int64_t?

And that comparison function, are you sure it doesn't break strict weak ordering? If it does, you will have undefined behavior.

"none of these worked..." What "does not work" mean. Add the complete error(if any).

@Someprogrammerdude I don't know about the OP but I'm fairly sure strict weak ordering is not being broken.

typedef long long i64; looks like you are learning C++ from bad or low quality sources. There should be no need to pass pointers to integers...    i64 final[100][2] = { er no this kind of coding will get you into trouble (assuming some kind of maximum size for data you don't yet know... bad ideea).  Do you know what structs are, and lambda functions?  struct entry { std::int64_t v1; std::int64_t};  and then make a std::vector<entry> for that and write a compare function (lambda) for that struct.

My advice find some better sources to learn C++ from first (e.g. learncpp.com). Also have a look at cppreference.com and how std::sort is explained there.

The fundamental problem here is that the elements you are trying to sort are arrays (i.e i64[2]) but arrays cannot be copied in C++, so std::sort cannot sort them. Your code is assuming the arrays are just like pointers, but they are not.
Here's your code rewritten to avoid this problem, I've create a struct int_pair that has a pair of integers instead of using a two element array. I've also replaced i64 with the standard type int64_t since it seems that is what you want.
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

struct int_pair
{
    int64_t first;
    int64_t second;
};

bool compare(const int_pair& a, const int_pair& b)
{
    if (a.second != b.second)
    {
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
    else
    {
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
}

int main(){

    int_pair final[100] = {
        { 0, 1},
        { 0, 1},
    };
    size_t final_stack = 2;

    //....(after inserting data)

    sort(final, final + final_stack, compare);
}

The lesson is - don't use arrays in C++.

don't use std::pair outside of (meta)template programming, just make a struct with two members (this adds semantics and makes the type unique)

@PepijnKramer I've updated my answer with your suggestion. It's also clearer for exposition I think.

nice :) Too bad we don't know more about OP's context otherwise we could have given better names to the members then first and second. I also would replace the "C" style array with a std::vector<int_pair>... (but don't do that or we will keep finding things to imporove ;) )

The problem is C-array. You have a C-array of C-arrays.
std::sort uses (move) assign operator to swap items. C-array doesn't have assign operator!
That is why this kind of error is reported:
x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:61:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_heap.h:355:15: error: array initializer must be an initializer list
  355 |           _ValueType __value = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first + __parent));
      |                      ^

Can't initialize i64[2] type with assignment of other i64[2] type.
https://godbolt.org/z/3xfjcx6cs
To fix it, it is better to use a C++ wrapper around C-arrays; std::array.
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

using i64 = std::int64_t;

bool compare(const std::array<i64, 2>& a, const std::array<i64, 2>& b)
{
    if (a[1] != b[1]) {
        return a[1] > b[1];
    } else {
        return a[0] < b[0];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<i64, 2>, 100> arr {
        { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 } },
    };
    i64 final_stack = 0;

    //....(after inserting data)

    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + final_stack, compare);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/Y36sKbo85

Or use std::vector
